# Fill zeroes with increment of the max value

Tags: pandas

I have the following dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'id':'a', 'val':1}, {'id':'b', 'val':2}, {'id':'c', 'val': 0}, {'id':'d', 'val':0}])
```

What I want is to replace 0's with +1 of the max value

The result I want is as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'id':'a', 'val':1}, {'id':'b', 'val':2}, {'id':'c', 'val': 3}, {'id':'d', 'val':4}])
```

I tried the following:

```
for _, r in df.iterrows(): 
    if r.val == 0: 
        r.val = df.val.max()+1
```

However, it there a one-line way to do the above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter only `0` rows with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and assign `range` with count `True`s values of condition with add maximum value and `1`, because python count from `0` in `range`:

```
df.loc[df['val'].eq(0), 'val'] = range(df['val'].eq(0).sum()) + df.val.max() + 1
print (df)
  id  val
0  a    1
1  b    2
2  c    3
3  d    4
```

Comment: Is there any reason to prefer `df['val'].eq(0)` over `df['val'] == 0`?

Comment: @Dan - It is trend today, I think main reason is `()` are not necessary if use `boolean indexing` like `df[df.a.eq(0) | df.b.ne(2)]` instead `df[(df.a == 0) | (df.b != 2)]`

Comment: @Dan - Also easy chained another functions like `df['val'].eq(0).sum()` vs `(df['val'] ==0).sum()`

Comment: So the reason is purely aesthetic? I guess if you do `df.val.eq(0).sum()` then your IDE gives you auto-completion the whole way through. But you lose that with `['val']`.

Comment: @Dan - yes, I agree. Also I personally prefer `[]` because it is more general - working nice with 2+ words columns names...

Comment: I prefer `[]` because it's more explicit that you're getting a column and not a DataFrame property. I guess it's just something I'll have to get used to reading :)

Comment: @Dan If you do `help(df['val'].eq)`, it'll give you an explanation as to why you might prefer to use `eq()`. I quote here the first lines : `eq(other, level=None, fill_value=None, axis=0) method of pandas.core.series.Series instance
     --- Return Equal to of series and other, element-wise (binary operator `eq`).
    
    --- Equivalent to ``series == other``, but with support to substitute a fill_value for
    missing data in one of the inputs.`